# "webView:didFailLoadWithError - Plug-in handled load" while loading the local video (.mov) and audio (.mp3) file

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I am listing all the downloaded media files in one page. Here i am using cordova-2.7.0.

It is displaying `"webView:didFailLoadWithError - Plug-in handled load"` error while trying to load video file (.mov) and audio file (.mp3).

I am using the following code to open the audio and video files using inAppBrowser.

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {});
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the android webview can open .mov and .mp3 files? and are you sure you are using the correct url?

Comment: I am using this method only for ios platform. yes url is correct and the url is the local stored file path

Comment: You have tagged the question as android. On iOS that code should work, but as you are using a very old version of phonegap, it might be a bug, you should update cordova to at least cordova 3.5 if you want to submit it to the apple store.